# How can I connect Rasberry Pi to internet via a 4G network?

Tags: raspbian, raspicam, server, docker

I want to connect Rasberry Pi to internet via 4G network.
The idea of my project is to take a picture (or stream a video) with Rasberry Pi camera and send it to a distant cloud (say a Docker container) or a server (I don't wanna process images on Rasberry Pi) via 4G network or Wifi network. I've seen people send small data over 2G network (GSM), but the problem is that my data will be large so I need to send it over 4G or Wifi.
I want to know how to make Rasberry Pi send data to a distant Cloud or a server.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I removed the "or at least wifi" and improved the focus of your title, since asking how to connect a Pi to wifi is already dealt with here, there, and everywhere exhaustively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the same as it would be for "how can I connect my laptop to a 4G network", etc.

1. Using a 4G USB modem; these come in stick size form factors and start at ~$20 US.
2. Using a portable 4G wifi router.
3. By connecting via phone (or other 4G connected device) hotspot.

All three of these require a valid SIM, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying WiFi is an option, then go for this. You need a WiFi capable Raspberry Pi board or a USB dongle. In addition to @goldilocks answer, there are also 4G HATs (e.g. from Waveshare) for the Raspberry Pi that allow for a compact integration and sometimes even have GPS included.